# Adding a rainbow gradient on just one bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, colors

So I have a df as follows:

```
colour_clicks <- structure(list(Color = c("beige", "black", "blue", "brown", "burgundy", 
"gray", "green", "navy blue", "of many colors", "olive", "pink", 
"red", "violet", "white"), avg = c(1.6799741044454, 2.48696524064171, 
2.67327546825034, 1.94043703007519, 1.26768060836502, 1.94480302693078, 
1.47427101200686, 1.09180327868852, 1.90684892897407, 1.11425902864259, 
1.35, 1.48054996646546, 1.49029356060606, 2.02322924600152)), row.names = c(NA, 
14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I want to make a bar plot to illustrate these averages, but I have two issues:

1. There is an "of many colors" bar I would like to be a rainbow gradient, is this possible for just one bar?
2. I want each bar to be a specific color but when I did it like this they aren't lining up; I believe it is due to the reorder function, any ideas?

```
ggplot(colour_clicks, aes(x = reorder(Color, -avg), y=avg, fill=Color)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(
                             "blue",
                             "black",
                             "white",
                             "gray",
                             "brown",
                             "orange",
                             "beige",
                             "violet",
                             "red",
                             "green",
                             "pink",
                             "orangered4",
                             "olivedrab",
                             "navyblue"
                             )) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (2), the fill variable you specified is `Color`, but the x-axis variable is `reorder(Color)`, so you have to change them to be the same variable. I prefer reordering before the call to `ggplot` to avoid these types of problems.

```r
colour_clicks %>% 
  mutate(Color = reorder(Color, desc(avg))) %>%   # reorder here, not within ggplot call
  ggplot(aes(x = Color, y=avg, fill=Color)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(
    "blue",
    "black",
    "white",
    "gray",
    "brown",
    "orange",
    "beige",
    "violet",
    "red",
    "green",
    "pink",
    "orangered4",
    "olivedrab",
    "navyblue"
  )) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: New bar order]

For (1), there is no great way to do this except making your own gradient bar. The basic method is to create a sequence from zero to the value of `avg`, then use that to generate a gradient with `colorRamp()`. Unfortunately, this outputs R, G, and B separately, so you have to convert that to hex. But it's not so bad really. Here it is.

```r
# Make the gradient
max_y <- colour_clicks$avg[colour_clicks$Color == "of many colors"]
pal <- c('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'violet')
color_generator <- colorRamp(pal)

df <- data.frame(
  y = seq(0, max_y, length.out = 100)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    R = color_generator(y/max_y)[,1],
    G = color_generator(y/max_y)[,2],
    B = color_generator(y/max_y)[,3],
    hexcol = sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", (round(R, 0)), 
                     (round(G, 0)), 
                     (round(B, 0)))
  )

colour_clicks %>% 
  mutate(Color = reorder(Color, desc(avg))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Color, y=avg, fill=Color)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(
    "blue", "black", "white", "gray", "brown", "orange", "beige", "violet",
    "red", "green", "pink", "orangered4", "olivedrab", "navyblue"
  )) +
  # Overlay the rainbow column on the old column
  geom_col(data = df, aes(x = 6, y = max_y/100, group = 1:100), fill = df$hexcol) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: with rainbow bar]

Comment: sound!  I have a love hate thing with ggplot, especially with formatting.  But this is really well explained and presented Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

that was actually really tough to find a solution, would be eager if anybody finds something more elegant.  I wouldn't know about the rainbow covered single bar. Be best if you ask a separate question explicitly to get more visability.

```
colour_clicks <- structure(list(Color = c("beige", "black", "blue", "brown", "burgundy", 
                                          "gray", "green", "navy blue", "of many colors", "olive", "pink", 
                                          "red", "violet", "white"), avg = c(1.6799741044454, 2.48696524064171, 
                                                                             2.67327546825034, 1.94043703007519, 1.26768060836502, 1.94480302693078, 
                                                                             1.47427101200686, 1.09180327868852, 1.90684892897407, 1.11425902864259, 
                                                                           1.35, 1.48054996646546, 1.49029356060606, 2.02322924600152)), row.names = 1:14, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 
p <- colour_clicks %>%mutate(r=rank(-avg))#%>%
ggplot(p)+geom_bar(stat='identity',aes(x = reorder(Color,-avg), y=avg,fill=Color))+
   #scale_x_discrete(limits = reorder(colour_clicks$Color,colour_clicks$avg))#+

  # geom_bar(stat="identity")+
   scale_fill_manual(values=c(
   "blue",
   "black",
   "white",
   "gray",
   "brown",
   "orange",
   "beige",
   "violet",
   "red",
   "green",
   "pink",
   "orangered4",
   "olivedrab",
   "navyblue"
)[p$r]) + geom_text(aes(x=Color,y=avg,label=round(avg,1)),nudge_y = 0.2)+
   theme(legend.position = "none")
```