Trying to see if there's a way to get 2 colors on a single bar within a ggplot bar plot
I've been doing some R practice with pokemon data (my usual go-to for test data) in order to make sure my skills don't get rusty and I'm wondering if there's a way to get 2 colors for a single bar plot. My knowledge of R is somewhat limited and I've scoured the documentation but have not found a solution within my knowledge and I'm certain someone knows that has more experience than me.
What I'm trying to do is make a graph that compares the various formes (yes, that's the in game term for the uninitiated) and their stats. While I know how to do the rest of what I want to do, my issue is that I would like to have the fill of the bar be a gradient of the pokemon's elemental type.
Using Rotom as an example, I want to indicate on the graph, using the fill, that Wash Rotom is an Electric-Water type, Mow Rotom is an Electric-Grass type, etc. I know I can get the primary type (which I have indicated through aes fill) but I want to get the secondary type in as a gradient if possible.
My data (relevant to the question) has the following headers:
PokedexNum, Name, PrimaryType, SecondaryType, Total (int), HP (int), Attack (int), Defense (int), SpAtk (int), SpDef (int), Speed (int), [...] , AltForme (Bool), FormeName, [...], FormeFamily, [...]

I've written the following
(readfile is just the excel file that I imported with the above headers.)
forme_comparisons <- readfile %>% 
  filter(AltForme) %>% 
  group_by(FormeFamily) %>% 
  select(Name, FormeName, FormeFamily, PrimaryType, SecondaryType, HP, Attack, Defense, SpAtk, SpDef, Speed) %>% filter(FormeFamily %in% c("Rotom", "Kyurem", "Giratina", "Deoxys")) # included this filter bit to only work with these 4 so I can actually see what I'm doing.

dfm <- melt(forme_comparisons, id.vars = c('FormeFamily', 'Name', 'FormeName', 'PrimaryType', 'SecondaryType'))

forme_comparison_plot <- dfm %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes( x = variable,
       y = value,
       group = FormeName,
       #color = FormeName,
       fill = PrimaryType) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity', color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = elementals)+
  facet_wrap(vars(FormeFamily)) +
  guides( x = guide_axis(angle = 90))


(Yes I know my writing style is a bit sloppy, but I'm trying my best here)
In theory, I think I can use scales to get the primary type and secondary type to show up.
here is the outcome of what I wrote.

sans the black outline that I added later and didn't feel like getting a screencap of.
Edit: Made some major overhauls using some of the solutions provided.
elementals <- function(givenelement) 
{
  
  elementalhex <- case_when(givenelement == "Normal" ~ '#A8A77A',
                givenelement == "Fire"~ '#EE8130',
                givenelement == "Water" ~ '#6390F0',
                givenelement == "Electric"~ '#F7D02C',
                givenelement == "Grass" ~ '#7AC74C',
                givenelement == "Ice" ~ '#96D9D6', 
                givenelement == "Fighting" ~ '#C22E28',
                givenelement == "Poison" ~ '#A33EA1',
                givenelement == "Ground" ~ '#E2BF65',
                givenelement == "Flying" ~ '#A98FF3',
                givenelement == "Psychic" ~ '#F95587',
                givenelement == "Bug" ~ '#A6B91A',
                givenelement == "Rock" ~ '#B6A136',
                givenelement == "Ghost" ~ '#735797',
                givenelement == "Dragon" ~ '#6F35FC',
                givenelement == "Dark" ~ '#705746',
                givenelement == "Steel" ~ '#B7B7CE',
                givenelement == "Fairy" ~ '#D685AD')
  return(elementalhex)
}

gradient_pairs <- function(concatpairs)
{
  typepairs <- str_split_1(concatpairs, " ")
  ret_pairs <- c(elementals(typepairs[1]), elementals(typepairs[2]))
  if(typepairs[2] == "NA")
  {
    ret_pairs <- c(elementals(typepairs[1]), elementals(typepairs[1]))
  }
  return(ret_pairs)
}



make_gradient <- function(fill1, fill2)
{
  grid::linearGradient(c(fill1, fill2), x2=1)
}

gradientmaker <- function(tibble1)
{
  returncollection <- tibble1 %>% pull(ConcatTypes)
  coloroutput1 <- c()
  coloroutput2 <- c()
  for (idkanymore in returncollection) {
    typematches <-  gradient_pairs(idkanymore)
    coloroutput1 <- append(coloroutput1, typematches[1])
    coloroutput2 <- append(coloroutput2, typematches[2])
  }
  my_fill <- c(coloroutput1, coloroutput2, returncollection)
  return(my_fill)
}




forme_comparisons <- readfile %>% 
  filter(AltForme) %>% 
  group_by(FormeFamily) %>% 
  select(Name, FormeName, FormeFamily, PrimaryType, SecondaryType, HP, Attack, Defense, SpAtk, SpDef, Speed) %>% 
  mutate(ConcatTypes = paste(PrimaryType, SecondaryType)) %>%filter(FormeFamily %in% c("Rotom", "Kyurem", "Shaymin", "Deoxys"))

dfm <- melt(forme_comparisons, id.vars = c('FormeFamily', 'Name', 'FormeName', 'PrimaryType', 'SecondaryType', 'ConcatTypes'))

co <- gradientmaker(dfm)

my_fill <- setNames(
    purrr::map2(co[1], co[2], make_gradient),
  co[3]
  )


forme_comparison_plot <- dfm %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes( x = variable,
       y = value,
       fill = ConcatTypes,
       group = FormeName) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge',stat='identity', color = 'black',) +
  facet_wrap(vars(FormeFamily)) +  
  guides( x = guide_axis(angle = 90))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_fills)

forme_comparison_plot

I think the only issue remaining is down to the packages because whenever I try to run it as well as the example code provided below by Axeman, I get this error in my console:
Warning in fill_alpha(coords$fill, coords$alpha) :
  Unable to check the capabilities of the png device.
Warning in fill_alpha(data$fill %||% "grey20", data$alpha) :
  Unable to check the capabilities of the png device.
Warning in fill_alpha(data$fill %||% "grey20", data$alpha) :
  Unable to check the capabilities of the png device.



Have you checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000454/9022665?

Run dput(dfm) and add the result to your question as an edit. It will make it easier to help you. The result will look something like structure(list(...).

@JonathanV.Solórzano Sheeeesh. Not exactly elegant but pretty damn similar. I however need it to change on a multitude of different entries. I could probably put it through a function so I don't have to write it every damn time, but this is very valuable. Thanks!

I would like to take a moment to just comment here and apologize for some of my atrocious code and its formatting.

It's bit tricky, but doable. An example:
fm <- data.frame(
  variable = c('HP', 'HP'),
  value = c(25, 30),
  FormeName = c('a', 'b'),
  primary_type = c('fire', 'water'),
  secondary_type = c('flying', 'grass')
)
fm$myfill <- paste(fm$primary_type, fm$secondary_type)

make_gradient <- function(fill1, fill2) {
  grid::linearGradient(c(fill1, fill2), x2 = 1)
}
my_fills <- setNames(
  purrr::map2(c('red', 'blue'), c('skyblue', 'green'), make_gradient),
  c('fire flying', 'water grass')
)

ggplot(fm, aes(variable, value, group = FormeName, fill = myfill)) +
  geom_col(color = 'black', position = 'dodge') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_fills)
  



Ooh. This looks great. I'm able to do this based on the code itself, right?

Yes. But because you didn't provide a reproducible example, I could not write anything specific. The idea is that you make sure my_fills has every combination of primary and secondary types, perhaps using expand.grid(unique(fm$primary_type), unique(fm$secondary_type)), and the correct names.

Sorry. Messed up the image I tried to post. I did attempt a variation of what you did using a probably less than pretty number of functions. I think your solution is what I need, but I have a whole new problem in the form of this error:
Warning in fill_alpha(data$fill %||% "grey20", data$alpha) :
Unable to check the capabilities of the png device.
It happens on both the new code that I wrote as well as a recreation of what you provided.

(Images of data are not reproducible.) I'm guessing that error has to do with device support for the gradients. First make sure you have an up-to-date R version. If that doesn't solve it, try a difference device, like e.g. ragg: https://github.com/r-lib/ragg.

That fixed it. although I used Cairo instead. That said, thank you so much for your help over all and sorry again for the less than helpful state of my results. I'll work on that for the future.

With the help of both that provided answers, I think I got a solution. It sure is... well, elegance wasn't exactly my end goal.
elementals <- function(givenelement) 
{
  
  elementalhex <- case_when(givenelement == "Normal" ~ '#A8A77A',
                givenelement == "Fire"~ '#EE8130',
                givenelement == "Water" ~ '#6390F0',
                givenelement == "Electric"~ '#F7D02C',
                givenelement == "Grass" ~ '#7AC74C',
                givenelement == "Ice" ~ '#96D9D6', 
                givenelement == "Fighting" ~ '#C22E28',
                givenelement == "Poison" ~ '#A33EA1',
                givenelement == "Ground" ~ '#E2BF65',
                givenelement == "Flying" ~ '#A98FF3',
                givenelement == "Psychic" ~ '#F95587',
                givenelement == "Bug" ~ '#A6B91A',
                givenelement == "Rock" ~ '#B6A136',
                givenelement == "Ghost" ~ '#735797',
                givenelement == "Dragon" ~ '#6F35FC',
                givenelement == "Dark" ~ '#705746',
                givenelement == "Steel" ~ '#B7B7CE',
                givenelement == "Fairy" ~ '#D685AD')
  return(elementalhex)
}

gradient_pairs <- function(concatpairs)
{
  typepairs <- stringr::str_split_1(concatpairs, " ")
  ret_pairs <- c(elementals(typepairs[1]), elementals(typepairs[2]))
  if(typepairs[2] == "NA")
  {
    ret_pairs <- c(elementals(typepairs[1]), elementals(typepairs[1]))
  }
  return(ret_pairs)
}

make_gradient <- function(fill1, fill2)
{
  grid::linearGradient(c(fill1, fill2), x2=1, group = FALSE)
}

gradientmaker <- function(tibble1){
  returncollection <- tibble1 %>% pull(ConcatTypes)
  coloroutput1 <- c()
  coloroutput2 <- c()
  namedelements <- c()
  
  for (idkanymore in returncollection) {
    typematches <-  gradient_pairs(idkanymore)
    coloroutput1 <- append(coloroutput1, typematches[1])
    coloroutput2 <- append(coloroutput2, typematches[2])
    
    typepairs <- stringr::str_split_1(idkanymore, " ")
    
    appendedelement <- idkanymore
    if(typepairs[2] == "NA") {
      appendedelement <- typepairs[1]
    }
    namedelements <- append(namedelements, appendedelement)
  }
  
  my_fill <- tibble(coloroutput1, coloroutput2, returncollection, namedelements)

  return(my_fill)
}


forme_comparisons <- readfile %>% 
  filter(AltForme) %>% 
  group_by(FormeFamily) %>% 
  select(Name, FormeName, FormeFamily, PrimaryType, SecondaryType, HP, Attack, Defense, SpAtk, SpDef, Speed) %>% 
  mutate(ConcatTypes = paste(PrimaryType, SecondaryType)) %>%
  filter(FormeFamily %in% c("Rotom", "Kyurem", "Shaymin", "Deoxys"))

dfm <- melt(forme_comparisons, id.vars = c('FormeFamily', 'Name', 'FormeName', 'PrimaryType', 'SecondaryType', 'ConcatTypes'))

co <- gradientmaker(dfm)

my_fills <- setNames(
    purrr::map2(co[["coloroutput1"]], co[["coloroutput2"]], make_gradient),
  co[["returncollection"]]
  )

forme_comparison_plot <- dfm %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes( x = variable,
       y = value,
       fill = ConcatTypes,
       group = FormeName) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge',stat='identity', color = 'black',) +
  facet_wrap(vars(FormeFamily)) +  
  guides( x = guide_axis(angle = 90))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_fills)

forme_comparison_plot



I will fix up the values of the labels later. I'm just glad I got it working. (the alpha and png device issue required me to change something in my graphics settings to Cairo.)
Since I continuously forgot to include my data, below I have a modified version of the csv that I used. I truncated it immensely since it was originally all entries up to and including the Kalos dex (over 800 lines total).
I was hesitant to share at first because I lost the link to the original, but I found it. The original was based on this: https://gist.github.com/armgilles/194bcff35001e7eb53a2a8b441e8b2c6#file-pokemon-csv
I added a few extra columns and modified quite a bit. I split legendary into Legendary and Mythic. I added region of discovery, a Mega marker, a Forme name, an alt forme marker, evolution family, forme family, stage of evolution, split evolution family, and designated groupings (fossils, pikachu clones, starting companions, etc). This was so I could do more data manipulation at a later point.
Also here is the link to the colors that I used for the graph: https://gist.github.com/apaleslimghost/0d25ec801ca4fc43317bcff298af43c3
PokedexNum,Name,PrimaryType,SecondaryType,Total,HP,Attack,Defense,SpAtk,SpDef,Speed,RegionOfOrigin,GenerationIntroduced,Legendary,Mythic,Mega,AltForme,FormeName,EvolutionLine,StageOfEvolution,FormeFamily,SplitEvolutionFamily,Groups
1,Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,318,45,49,49,65,65,45,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Bulbasaur,1,,,Starting Companions
2,Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,405,60,62,63,80,80,60,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Bulbasaur,2,,,Starting Companions
3,Venusaur,Grass,Poison,525,80,82,83,100,100,80,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Bulbasaur,3,,,
3,Venusaur,Grass,Poison,625,80,100,123,122,120,80,Kanto,6,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,,Bulbasaur,Mega,,,
133,Eevee,Normal,,325,55,55,50,45,65,55,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Eevee,1,,Eevee,"Eeveelutions, Starting Companions"
134,Vaporeon,Water,,525,130,65,60,110,95,65,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Eevee,2,,Eevee,Eeveelutions
135,Jolteon,Electric,,525,65,65,60,110,95,130,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Eevee,2,,Eevee,Eeveelutions
136,Flareon,Fire,,525,65,130,60,95,110,65,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Eevee,2,,Eevee,Eeveelutions
137,Porygon,Normal,,395,65,60,70,85,75,40,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Porygon,1,,,Artificial
138,Omanyte,Rock,Water,355,35,40,100,90,55,35,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Omanyte,1,,,Fossil
139,Omastar,Rock,Water,495,70,60,125,115,70,55,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Omanyte,2,,,Fossil
140,Kabuto,Rock,Water,355,30,80,90,55,45,55,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Kabuto,1,,,Fossil
141,Kabutops,Rock,Water,495,60,115,105,65,70,80,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Kabuto,2,,,Fossil
142,Aerodactyl,Rock,Flying,515,80,105,65,60,75,130,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Fossil
142,Aerodactyl,Rock,Flying,615,80,135,85,70,95,150,Kanto,6,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,,,Mega,,,Fossil
143,Snorlax,Normal,,540,160,110,65,65,110,30,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Munchlax,2,,,
144,Articuno,Ice,Flying,580,90,85,100,95,125,85,Kanto,1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Legendary Birds
145,Zapdos,Electric,Flying,580,90,90,85,125,90,100,Kanto,1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Legendary Birds
146,Moltres,Fire,Flying,580,90,100,90,125,85,90,Kanto,1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Legendary Birds
147,Dratini,Dragon,,300,41,64,45,50,50,50,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Dratini,1,,,
148,Dragonair,Dragon,,420,61,84,65,70,70,70,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Dratini,2,,,Starting Companions
149,Dragonite,Dragon,Flying,600,91,134,95,100,100,80,Kanto,1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Dratini,3,,,
150,Mewtwo,Psychic,,680,106,110,90,154,90,130,Kanto,1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,Mega Mewtwo,"Mew Duo, Artificial"
150,Mewtwo,Psychic,Fighting,780,106,190,100,154,100,130,Kanto,6,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,X,,Mega,Mega Mewtwo,Mega Mewtwo,"Mew Duo, Artificial"
150,Mewtwo,Psychic,,780,106,150,70,194,120,140,Kanto,6,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,Y,,Mega,Mega Mewtwo,Mega Mewtwo,"Mew Duo, Artificial"
151,Mew,Psychic,,600,100,100,100,100,100,100,Kanto,1,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Mew Duo
152,Chikorita,Grass,,318,45,49,65,49,65,45,Johto,2,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Chikorita,1,,,Starting Companions
153,Bayleef,Grass,,405,60,62,80,63,80,60,Johto,2,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Chikorita,2,,,
154,Meganium,Grass,,525,80,82,100,83,100,80,Johto,2,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Chikorita,3,,,
194,Wooper,Water,Ground,210,55,45,45,25,25,15,Johto,2,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Wooper,1,,,
195,Quagsire,Water,Ground,430,95,85,85,65,65,35,Johto,2,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Wooper,2,,,
196,Espeon,Psychic,,525,65,65,60,130,95,110,Johto,2,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Eevee,2,,Eevee,"Eeveelutions, Starting Companions"
197,Umbreon,Dark,,525,95,65,110,60,130,65,Johto,2,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Eevee,2,,Eevee,"Eeveelutions, Starting Companions"
199,Slowking,Water,Psychic,490,95,75,80,100,110,30,Johto,2,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Slowpoke,2,,Slowbro/Slowking,
265,Wurmple,Bug,,195,45,45,35,20,30,20,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Wurmple,1,,Wurmple,
266,Silcoon,Bug,,205,50,35,55,25,25,15,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Wurmple,2,,Wurmple,
267,Beautifly,Bug,Flying,395,60,70,50,100,50,65,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Wurmple,3,,Wurmple,
268,Cascoon,Bug,,205,50,35,55,25,25,15,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Wurmple,2,,Wurmple,
269,Dustox,Bug,Poison,385,60,50,70,50,90,65,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Wurmple,3,,Wurmple,
280,Ralts,Psychic,Fairy,198,28,25,25,45,35,40,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Ralts,1,,Gardevoir/Gallade,
281,Kirlia,Psychic,Fairy,278,38,35,35,65,55,50,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Ralts,2,,Gardevoir/Gallade,
282,Gardevoir,Psychic,Fairy,518,68,65,65,125,115,80,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Ralts,3,,Gardevoir/Gallade,
282,Gardevoir,Psychic,Fairy,618,68,85,65,165,135,100,Hoenn,6,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,,Ralts,Mega,,Gardevoir/Gallade,
290,Nincada,Bug,Ground,266,31,45,90,30,30,40,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Nincada,1,,Ninjask/Shedinja,
291,Ninjask,Bug,Flying,456,61,90,45,50,50,160,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Nincada,2,,Ninjask/Shedinja,
292,Shedinja,Bug,Ghost,236,1,90,45,30,30,40,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Nincada,2,,Ninjask/Shedinja,
311,Plusle,Electric,,405,60,50,40,85,75,95,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Electric Rodents
312,Minun,Electric,,405,60,40,50,75,85,95,Hoenn,3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Electric Rodents
382,Kyogre,Water,,670,100,100,90,150,140,90,Hoenn,3,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Super-ancient
382,KyogrePrimal Kyogre,Water,,770,100,150,90,180,160,90,Hoenn,3,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Super-ancient
383,Groudon,Ground,,670,100,150,140,100,90,90,Hoenn,3,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Super-ancient
383,GroudonPrimal Groudon,Ground,Fire,770,100,180,160,150,90,90,Hoenn,3,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Super-ancient
384,Rayquaza,Dragon,Flying,680,105,150,90,150,90,95,Hoenn,3,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Super-ancient
384,Rayquaza,Dragon,Flying,780,105,180,100,180,100,115,Hoenn,6,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,,,Mega,,,Super-ancient
385,Jirachi,Steel,Psychic,600,100,100,100,100,100,100,Hoenn,3,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,
386,Deoxys,Psychic,,600,50,150,50,150,50,150,Hoenn,3,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Normal Forme,,,Deoxys,,Extraterrestrial
386,Deoxys,Psychic,,600,50,180,20,180,20,150,Hoenn,3,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Attack Forme,,,Deoxys,,Extraterrestrial
386,Deoxys,Psychic,,600,50,70,160,70,160,90,Hoenn,3,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Defense Forme,,,Deoxys,,Extraterrestrial
386,Deoxys,Psychic,,600,50,95,90,95,90,180,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Speed Forme,,,Deoxys,,Extraterrestrial
399,Bidoof,Normal,,250,59,45,40,35,40,31,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Bidoof,1,,,
400,Bibarel,Normal,Water,410,79,85,60,55,60,71,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Bidoof,2,,,
401,Kricketot,Bug,,194,37,25,41,25,41,25,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Kricketot,1,,,
402,Kricketune,Bug,,384,77,85,51,55,51,65,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Kricketot,2,,,
412,Burmy,Bug,,224,40,29,45,29,45,36,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Burmy,1,,Wormadam/Mothim,
413,Wormadam,Bug,Grass,424,60,59,85,79,105,36,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Plant Cloak,Burmy,2,Wormadam Cloaks,Wormadam/Mothim,
413,Wormadam,Bug,Ground,424,60,79,105,59,85,36,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Sandy Cloak,Burmy,2,Wormadam Cloaks,Wormadam/Mothim,
413,Wormadam,Bug,Steel,424,60,69,95,69,95,36,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Trash Cloak,Burmy,2,Wormadam Cloaks,Wormadam/Mothim,Artificial
414,Mothim,Bug,Flying,424,70,94,50,94,50,66,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Burmy,2,,Wormadam/Mothim,
417,Pachirisu,Electric,,405,60,45,70,45,90,95,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Electric Rodents
418,Buizel,Water,,330,55,65,35,60,30,85,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Buizel,1,,,
419,Floatzel,Water,,495,85,105,55,85,50,115,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Buizel,2,,,
420,Cherubi,Grass,,275,45,35,45,62,53,35,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Cherubi,1,,,
421,Cherrim,Grass,,450,70,60,70,87,78,85,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,,Cherubi,2,Cherrim,,
421,Cherrim,Grass,,519,70,90,70,87,117,85,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Sunshine,Cherubi,2,Cherrim,,
470,Leafeon,Grass,,525,65,110,130,60,65,95,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Eevee,2,,Eevee,Eeveelutions
471,Glaceon,Ice,,525,65,60,110,130,95,65,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Eevee,2,,Eevee,Eeveelutions
475,Gallade,Psychic,Fighting,518,68,125,65,65,115,80,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Ralts,3,,Gardevoir/Gallade,
475,Gallade,Psychic,Fighting,618,68,165,95,65,115,110,Sinnoh,6,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,,Ralts,Mega,,Gardevoir/Gallade,
479,Rotom,Electric,Ghost,440,50,50,77,95,77,91,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,,,,Rotom,,Artificial
479,Rotom,Electric,Fire,520,50,65,107,105,107,86,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Heat Rotom,,,Rotom,,Artificial
479,Rotom,Electric,Water,520,50,65,107,105,107,86,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Wash Rotom,,,Rotom,,Artificial
479,Rotom,Electric,Ice,520,50,65,107,105,107,86,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Frost Rotom,,,Rotom,,Artificial
479,Rotom,Electric,Flying,520,50,65,107,105,107,86,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Fan Rotom,,,Rotom,,Artificial
479,Rotom,Electric,Grass,520,50,65,107,105,107,86,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Mow Rotom,,,Rotom,,Artificial
487,Giratina,Ghost,Dragon,680,150,100,120,100,120,90,Sinnoh,4,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Altered Forme,,,Giratina,,Pokemon of Myth
487,Giratina,Ghost,Dragon,680,150,120,100,120,100,90,Sinnoh,4,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Origin Forme,,,Giratina,,Pokemon of Myth
492,Shaymin,Grass,,600,100,100,100,100,100,100,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Land Forme,,,Shaymin,,
492,Shaymin,Grass,Flying,600,100,103,75,120,75,127,Sinnoh,4,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Sky Forme,,,Shaymin,,
554,Darumaka,Fire,,315,70,90,45,15,45,50,Unova,5,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Darumaka,1,,,
555,Darmanitan,Fire,,480,105,140,55,30,55,95,Unova,5,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Standard Mode,Darumaka,2,Darmanitan,,
555,Darmanitan,Fire,Psychic,540,105,30,105,140,105,55,Unova,5,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Zen Mode,Darumaka,2,Darmanitan,,
587,Emolga,Electric,Flying,428,55,75,60,75,60,103,Unova,5,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Electric Rodents
641,Tornadus,Flying,,580,79,115,70,125,80,111,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Incarnate Forme,,,Tornadus,,Forces of Nature
641,Tornadus,Flying,,580,79,100,80,110,90,121,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Therian Forme,,,Tornadus,,Forces of Nature
642,Thundurus,Electric,Flying,580,79,115,70,125,80,111,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Incarnate Forme,,,Thundurus,,Forces of Nature
642,Thundurus,Electric,Flying,580,79,105,70,145,80,101,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Therian Forme,,,Thundurus,,Forces of Nature
643,Reshiram,Dragon,Fire,680,100,120,100,150,120,90,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Tao Trio
644,Zekrom,Dragon,Electric,680,100,150,120,120,100,90,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Tao Trio
645,Landorus,Ground,Flying,600,89,125,90,115,80,101,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Incarnate Forme,,,Landorus,,Forces of Nature
645,Landorus,Ground,Flying,600,89,145,90,105,80,91,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Therian Forme,,,Landorus,,Forces of Nature
646,Kyurem,Dragon,Ice,660,125,130,90,130,90,95,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,,,,Kyurem,,"Tao Trio, Extraterrestrial"
646,Kyurem,Dragon,Ice,700,125,170,100,120,90,95,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Black,,,Kyurem,,"Tao Trio, Extraterrestrial"
646,Kyurem,Dragon,Ice,700,125,120,90,170,100,95,Unova,5,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,White,,,Kyurem,,"Tao Trio, Extraterrestrial"
647,Keldeo,Water,Fighting,580,91,72,90,129,90,108,Unova,5,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Ordinary Forme,,,Keldeo,,Swords of Justice
647,Keldeo,Water,Fighting,580,91,72,90,129,90,108,Unova,5,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Resolute Forme,,,Keldeo,,Swords of Justice
648,Meloetta,Normal,Psychic,600,100,77,77,128,128,90,Unova,5,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Aria Forme,,,Meloetta,,
648,Meloetta,Normal,Fighting,600,100,128,90,77,77,128,Unova,5,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Pirouette Forme,,,Meloetta,,
649,Genesect,Bug,Steel,600,71,120,95,120,95,99,Unova,5,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Artificial
670,Floette,Fairy,,371,54,45,47,75,98,52,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Flabebe,2,,,
670,FloetteEternal Flower,Fairy,,551,74,65,67,125,128,92,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,
677,Espurr,Psychic,,355,62,48,54,63,60,68,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Espurr,1,,Meowstic,
678,MeowsticMale,Psychic,,466,74,48,76,83,81,104,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Espurr,2,,Meowstic,
678,MeowsticFemale,Psychic,,466,74,48,76,83,81,104,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Espurr,2,,Meowstic,
679,Honedge,Steel,Ghost,325,45,80,100,35,37,28,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Honedge,1,,,
680,Doublade,Steel,Ghost,448,59,110,150,45,49,35,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Honedge,2,,,
681,Aegislash,Steel,Ghost,520,60,150,50,150,50,60,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Blade Forme,Honedge,3,Aegislash,,
681,Aegislash,Steel,Ghost,520,60,50,150,50,150,60,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Shield Forme,Honedge,3,Aegislash,,
700,Sylveon,Fairy,,525,95,65,65,110,130,60,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,Eevee,2,,Eevee,Eeveelutions
710,Pumpkaboo,Ghost,Grass,335,49,66,70,44,55,51,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Average Size,Pumpkaboo,1,Pumpkaboo,,
710,Pumpkaboo,Ghost,Grass,335,44,66,70,44,55,56,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Small Size,Pumpkaboo,1,Pumpkaboo,,
710,Pumpkaboo,Ghost,Grass,335,54,66,70,44,55,46,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Large Size,Pumpkaboo,1,Pumpkaboo,,
710,Pumpkaboo,Ghost,Grass,335,59,66,70,44,55,41,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Super Size,Pumpkaboo,1,Pumpkaboo,,
711,Gourgeist,Ghost,Grass,494,65,90,122,58,75,84,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Average Size,Pumpkaboo,2,Gourgeist,,
711,Gourgeist,Ghost,Grass,494,55,85,122,58,75,99,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Small Size,Pumpkaboo,2,Gourgeist,,
711,Gourgeist,Ghost,Grass,494,75,95,122,58,75,69,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Large Size,Pumpkaboo,2,Gourgeist,,
711,Gourgeist,Ghost,Grass,494,85,100,122,58,75,54,Kalos,6,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Super Size,Pumpkaboo,2,Gourgeist,,
716,Xerneas,Fairy,,680,126,131,95,131,98,99,Kalos,6,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Aura Trio
717,Yveltal,Dark,Flying,680,126,131,95,131,98,99,Kalos,6,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,Aura Trio
718,Zygarde,Dragon,Ground,600,108,100,121,81,95,95,Kalos,6,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,50% Forme,,,Zygarde,,Aura Trio
719,Diancie,Rock,Fairy,600,50,100,150,100,150,50,Kalos,6,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,,,,,,
719,Diancie,Rock,Fairy,700,50,160,110,160,110,110,Kalos,6,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,,,Mega,,,
720,Hoopa,Psychic,Ghost,600,80,110,60,150,130,70,Kalos,6,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Hoopa Confined,,,Hoopa,,
720,Hoopa,Psychic,Dark,680,80,160,60,170,130,80,Kalos,6,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,Hoopa Unbound,,,Hoopa,,

